# DevForce 2010 Top n query

Tags: sql, devforce, top-n

I'm wanting to remove duplicate records from a table that has over 2 million rows.  I have an IEntityQuery that does the grouping and counting and returning where count() > 1.  The problem is this query also could return over a million rows.  I would like to do a TOP 100 query using DevForce, but I haven't found a way to do this.  I realize that I can use .Take(100) after Execute(), but this requires returning all of the rows and then taking 100.  I want the query to only return 100 rows from the database.  This seems like a fairly common need, but so far I have not been able to find any examples on the web or IdeaBlade's site on how to accomplish this.

Thanks!!!

```
var query = from log in Manager.Logs
            select logs;

 query
      .Execute()
      .ToList()
      .Take(100);  --Bad for this query--
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the Take() before the Execute the generated SQL will contain the Top operator.   So something like this:

```
var query = from log in Manager.Logs
            select log;
query
      .Take(100)
      .ToList();
```

If your actual query type is more complex due to grouping you may need to do a cast to use the Take method.